# Get all textFields value from titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I have created dynamically textFields, from an object :

```
var fields = [{field:'telephone', hint:'Telephone'},{field:email, hint:'Email} ... ];
```

**And create the fields :**

```
 _.each(fields, function(item){
    var field = Ti.UI.createTextField({
        id : item.field,
        hintText : item.hint,
    });
    $.form.add(field)

})
```

**I create a button :**

```
var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Send All'
});
$.form.add(button)
```

Now i want to store all textFields values to a Global object when click to button.

```
var output = [];
$.button.addEventListener(function(){
    /* I want to loop to each created textFields above and get value from id */
    _.each(fields, function(item){
        output.push(item.value);
    });
    Alloy.Globals.form = output;
});
```

But this not working, i cannot get values of created fields when clicking on the button. 
Do you have an idea how to handle this please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by using children property

e.g

```
$.button.addEventListener(function(){
    _.each($.form.children, function(item){
       if(item.apiName == "Ti.UI.TextField"){   
        output.push(item.value);
      }
});
Alloy.Globals.form = output;
});
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your response, it seems a good way, i have just one question : event fields are dynamically created i could get theme throught $.form.children ? big thanks

Comment: Yes you will get it by children property, doesn't matter it's dynamic or static.